# R dynamic equation

Tags: r, dynamic, time-series

Using R and estimating a simple equation by least squares that has the dependent variable as a independent (explanatory, right hand side) variable, I want to forecast out of sample and use the dependent variable forecasts in the out of sample period as a lag for each step ahead.
I.e., I want to extend forecasts of y to be outside the data period

```
 a <- lm( y ~  x + lag(y,1), data= dset1)
 b <- forecast(a,newdata=dset2)
```

where dset2 has the full period of extra x variables, but not the lagged y.

Here is an example using the AirPassengers data set, where dset2 was created with some missing ap data.  The results below show only row 143 gets filled in not 144 because forecast did not have the 143 lag. 
I looked at the dyn dynlm and forecast packages but nonw seem to work with type of model. (I do not want to restate as an ARMA or a VAR)

What package can easily do this, or am I using forecast incorrectly?
I can loop and step ahead on period at a time, but rather not do that.

```
##Example case using airline data
data("AirPassengers", package = "datasets")
ap <- log(AirPassengers)
ap <- as.ts(ap)
d1 <- data.frame(ap, index= as.Date(ap))
m1 <- lm(ap ~ lag(ap,1), data=d1)
m2 <- dynlm(ap ~ lag(ap,1), data=d1)
m3 <- dyn(lm(ap ~ lag(ap,1), data=d1))
summary(m3)
##Neither  lm or dyn or dynlm obects worked as I want

## Try forecast missing values, 2 steps, rows 143 and 144
d2 <- d1
d2$apx = d2$ap
d2$apx[143:144]= NA
mx <- lm(apx ~ lag(apx,1), data=d2)
b <- forecast(mx,newdata=d2)
```

Results:

```
> b
 Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
   1             NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
   2       4.756850 4.619213 4.894488 4.545513 4.968188
   3       4.807218 4.669783 4.944653 4.596191 5.018245
  ....
 140       6.411559 6.273546 6.549572 6.199644 6.623474
 141       6.386407 6.248507 6.524306 6.174667 6.598146
 142       6.216154 6.078941 6.353368 6.005467 6.426841
 143       6.122453 5.985553 6.259354 5.912247 6.332659
 144             NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

other lm like objects produced errors for forecast

```
mx <- dynlm(apx ~ lag(apx,1), data=d2)
b <- forecast(mx,newdata=d2)
```

> Error in forecast.lm(mx, newdata = d2) :    invalid type/length
>   (symbol/0) in vector allocation

```
mx <- dyn(lm(apx ~ lag(apx,1), data=d2))
b <- forecast(mx,newdata=d2)
```

> Error in predict.lm(object, newdata = newdata, se.fit = TRUE, interval
>   = "prediction",  :    formal argument "se.fit" matched by multiple actual arguments

Comment: `d1 <- data.frame(ap, index= as.Date(ap))` results in an error.

Comment: Sorry here are the librairses I had loaded.  library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

library(dyn)
library(dynlm)
library(forecast) I suspect library(zoo) is needed and lag(y,-1) would be used without it.  or just use d1 <- data.frame(ap).  I do want to treat as a data frame with a date index for other reasons